# Strongswan tunnel isn't working after restarting server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, ssh-tunnel, tunnel

I'm having an IPSec tunnel created between two AWS regions, using strongswan. When one region servers are restarted then strongswan wasn't able to ping to the private servers in the second region. It was working before. Is it a good idea to have an AWS resource (VPC peering) for the tunnel to create, so that I could solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in general it's a better idea to use VPC peering instead of IPsec tunnels to connect multiple VPCs. VPC peering is managed by AWS and reduces your maintenance effort. You can only apply VPC peering between a few regions. See the blog post for more details.

See guide for further details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/Welcome.html

For connecting multiple regions with VPC peering see this blog post:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-almost-inter-region-vpc-peering/

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add (or switch) the parameter `auto=start` to your *ipsec.conf* for that tunnel connection.

If you use `auto=add` only on both sides, the tunnel connection establishement won't be started by any of the nodes.

Notice though that if you use `auto=start` on both sites, you might run into trouble if both sites try to establish the tunnel **at the same time**. This can happen if you restart StrongSwan simultaneously for example.